# link word doc to content control in another word doc

Tags: microsoft-word

We require several separate Word 2007 documents to share a few simple pieces of information, including project name, address, and publication date, in the documents header (other pieces of information in the header are unique. My approach has been to create a short, shared file with Content Controls that contain this information. The documents link to this central document using ÏNCLUDETEXT bookmark (each Content Control has an associated bookmark). It works OK, but I would have thought Content Controls had a more elegant way of sharing information across documents without using VB or Fields. E.g., but using another content control that can link across files. Can linking to a Content Control in another file be done with another Content Control or am I on the right track using Fields and or VB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be a comment, really, but too long.

You don't say how you are using your content controls or whether you want users to be able to update their values via any of the documents, or only through the "shared" document.

If any of your users are on Mac, INCLUDETEXT fields are probably the only way to go, and even they will cause difficulties because of the different path and file naming conventions.

AFAIK there is no facility to link content controls to content controls in other documents except via LINK fields or INCLUDETEXT fields. These days I would avoid LINK fields because they often spell trouble. Nor can you map a content control to a custom XML part in another document (as far as I know).

If content controls and the fact that Word does automatic propagation of values are what you want, personally I would probably do things this way:

1. Define your common data and an XML structure to house it.
2. Decide that it should be read-only data except in the "master" copy of the XML.
3. Depending on who or what is maintaining it, you could make the "master" either a standalone XML document, or a Word document with a custom XML part. In the latter case I would create a single Word document with an updateable content control linked to to each item in the Part. You get some cheap documentation of the values, and updates could in theory trigger copying of the data to other documents sharing the values.
4. Ensure that your XML structure has single child element within the Document element, e.g. like this:
   `<xmlOuter><xmlInner><your elements.../></xmlInner></xmlOuter>`
5. Use that XML to create the `CustomXMLPart` in each document where you need to share the values. In those documents, make any content controls linked to the data non-updatable.
6. Whenever you modify your common data, replace the `<xmlInner>` child sub-tree of the `<xmlOuter>`. That should prevent the problem where replacing the XML (e.g. by deleting/re-creating the part) breaks the links between content controls and the XML Part. But I would verify that for yourself.
7. Every document could, in theory, have AutoOpen code that grabbed the current version of the common data.

Comment: Many thanks for the thoughts. My comfort level with xml is nil, so I'm now looking for a solution in VBA and posted the question here http://superuser.com/questions/762607/accessing-content-controls-in-closed-document-with-vba